# canOverrideExistingModule issue in react-native application

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

Hello every one i tried to create an camera app with react-native-camera module
when i tried to run this app on my device (android mobile) getting following error. Can any one please provide me solution for this ?

[image: Getting issue with camaera module]

Answer (score 1):

Go to file "MainApplication.java" (under .\android\app\src\main\java\com\projectName)

Make sure that under getPackages() function you don't have duplicate lines (in my case I had "new RCTCameraPackage()" twice).

Fix duplicate imports as well.