# How to set canOverrideExistingModule=true in React Native?

Tags: react-native, android-virtual-device

I build an android app using React Native,build got success but when i run app in my AVD it show up a error:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [canOverrideExistingModule issue in react-native application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126722/canoverrideexistingmodule-issue-in-react-native-application)

Comment: I got this as well. And there was no duplicated new package line. I think it might have something to do with Instabug. I got this problem after adding Instabug

Answer (score -4, accepted):

What you can try is first remove the duplicate declarations in method `getPackages()` of your `MainApplication.java` file.

If you're using Android Studio this file is in `app > java` otherwise you can find it in `android/app/src/main/java/com/yourAppName/yourProjectName/MainApplication.java`.

Then try again `react-native run-android`